# how to surf internet from web view in android

Tags: android, android-webview

Hey guys I want to surf internet from webview in android and i am getting the page for which i have provided url in edittext.But when click on a link inside webview then it is unable to find that page.I have provided internet permission in manifest file and taken web view in layout.
This is my main activity which needs to be corrected somewhere.Thanks in advance and help done will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et1;
    Button btn;
    WebView wv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new mybrowser());
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String url = et1.getText().toString();
                  wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                  wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                  wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                  wv.loadUrl("https://"+url);
                  wv.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }


    class mybrowser extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            String url1=et1.getText().toString();
            view.loadUrl(url1);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to do like

```
 class mybrowser extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and remove   `String url1=et1.getText().toString();`